# Docker IBM Java in multistage build

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I want to use the docker [multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) in my `Dockerfile` to pull the Java image from [IBM](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/ibmjava/) `ibmjava:latest` and use in my image that is

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE 
ibmjava             latest              8180a8f0188a        2 weeks ago         310 MB
```

Using the multi-stage I would do

```
FROM ibmjava:latest AS IBMJAVA
```

This will install `java` in `/opt/ibm/java/jre/bin/java`.

and then I should copy the install folder to my image like

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY --from=IBMJAVA /opt/ibm/java /opt/ibm/java
```

Is this approach correct?

*NOTE*
Currently I'm using `curl` to fetch a `tar.gz` of java

```
RUN curl https://myserver.com/jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz > jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
RUN tar xvzf jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz -C $ROOT && \
    chown -R root:root jdk-9.0.1 && \
    rm jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
ENV JAVA_HOME $ROOT/jdk-9.0.1
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin/
```

Comment: Why not use the ibmjava image directly?

Comment: @Henry because I need a specific `FROM` that is not in the `ibmjava`.

Comment: You're better off getting a tar file or other "normal" installation medium and installing it normally in your application image (`RUN tar xzf ...`).

Comment: @DavidMaze yes that is the way I'm doing right now. Problem is that this will cause every time the operation to run and not to be cached in an layer, since I fetch java tar `jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz` with `curl` (cannot be local).

Comment: Any `RUN` command is cacheable, provided nothing has changed before it.  (Try putting this before anything that `COPY`s from your local tree.)

Comment: @DavidMaze interesting. Just updated the question. I'm doing this just after `RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \...` and before any `COPY` command.